Angular 17 SSR => "document is not defined" when using quilljs
I am using QuillJs ... After installing it; SSR stops working. I tried JSDOM and other advices online. Looking for the most modern advice. Please see my reproduction of the issue.
Reproduction
https://github.com/ohabash/ng-ssr-quill
Error in server (ng serve)

[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /main.server.mjs:
|- ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.eval (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:7661:12)
at webpack_require (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:36:30)
at Object.eval (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:1030:1)
at webpack_require (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:36:30)
at Object.eval (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:5655:14)
at webpack_require (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:36:30)
at Object.eval (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:10045:13)
at webpack_require (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:36:30)
at Object.eval (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:11557:18)
at webpack_require (/Users/Sites/test-ssr/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js:36:30)

